# Bootstrap modal and cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, popup

I have created a bootstrap modal popup and it appears and disappears perfectly. What I need to do is check to see if there is a cookie stored and only have the popup appear once while the user is on the site. I have a close button on it too. At the moment it appears every time I refresh the page and I'm not sure how to get it to work. I have seen a couple of examples by googling but nothing works for me. Can anyone help? Thanks

Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.cookie != "") {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#myModalClose").click(function () {
          $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        });
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="inner-modal">
        <div class="modal-container">
            <p>some text</p>
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal">Hide this message</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if (document.cookie != "")` be `if (document.cookie == "")`?

Comment: Hi @DavidG When I change it from != to == my modal popup breaks.

Comment: Breaks in what way? It's probably better anyway to write `if (!document.cookie)`

Comment: In the sense that the modal popup is displayed on screen all the time, the content behind it isn't greyed out like it should be and the close button doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your logic is a bit back to front. You need to check if no cookie has yet been set then show the modal. Also you need to set the cookie afterwards so it doesn't happen again.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    //if cookie hasn't been set...
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("ModalShown=true")<0) {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        //Modal has been shown, now set a cookie so it never comes back
        $("#myModalClose").click(function () {
            $("#myModal").modal("hide");
        });
        document.cookie = "ModalShown=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
    <div class="inner-modal">
        <div class="modal-container">
            <p>some text</p>
            <button id="myModalClose" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#myModal">Hide this message</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the code above but nothing happened. The modal popup is on screen all the time, doesnt do anything or disappear.

Comment: I've fixed it now (I really shouldn't write code without testing it!)

Comment: Thanks @DavidG for updating the answer, however when I hit refresh the modal pops up again and then freezes on screen and stops working. Can't press the close button or do anything.

Comment: Something else may be interfering, it works fine for me. Here is an example in [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/EZRTC1lXtJ) (open it in incognito mode in browser to test as a new user)

Comment: Thanks @DavidG I tested it as you suggested and it does work, unfortunately for me it didn't work when I added it to my code. There must have been some kind of interference but I have no idea what it was because I literally had the plain html and the javascript so I couldn't figure out what was causing it to not work for me. Eventually I ended up using the jquery-cookie.js plugin -> https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie.